# Initializing a base class

Tags: c++

From what I could gather, this should work, no?

```
struct ViewOfFile {
    void* p = nullptr;

    ViewOfFile(HANDLE hMap, int64_t OffsetB, SIZE_T SizeB, bool WriteAccess) {
        DWORD ViewAccessMode = FILE_MAP_READ | (WriteAccess ? FILE_MAP_WRITE : NULL);
        LARGE_INTEGER LI = { OffsetB };
        p = MapViewOfFile(hMap, ViewAccessMode, LI.HighPart, LI.LowPart, SizeB);
        if (p == nullptr) throw Exception("ViewOfFile: Failed to create view.");
    }
    ~ViewOfFile() {
        if (p) UnmapViewOfFile(p);
    }
    operator void*() const { return p; }
    operator char*() const { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(p); }
};

template <typename T>
struct ViewOfFileAs : ViewOfFile {
    T* as;
    ViewOfFile(HANDLE hMap, int64_t OffsetB, SIZE_T SizeB, bool WriteAccess) : ViewOfFile(hMap, OffsetB, SizeB, WriteAccess) {
        as = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
    }
};
```

however, the template class constructor gives me an error "Only a constructor can have base/member initializer list". Why is this happening?

Comment: Unrelated but why do you use `NULL` macro to write to an integer value?

Comment: You might want to rename the template constructor from ViewOfFile to ViewOfFileAs

Comment: @NeilKirk because its supposed to be 0 and is purple like the other macro, its a fashion choice

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup has said many times that there is no reason to ever use NULL in a properly written C++ program. 'Fashion choice' indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a typo in the definition of your template struct: you wrote `ViewOfFile` instead of `ViewOfFileAs` as a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewOfFile(HANDLE hMap, int64_t OffsetB, SIZE_T SizeB, bool WriteAccess)
```

Should be

```
ViewOfFileAs(HANDLE hMap, int64_t OffsetB, SIZE_T SizeB, bool WriteAccess)
```